# Single word synonym for "Decays into"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm a non-native speaker and was looking for a single word which has the same (or close to the same) meaning as 'decays into' – where something becomes less than it was by losing (little) parts of itself which turn into something else.

Does such a word exist?

**Update:**
Some more info on the context in which this word would be used. For a fictional/fantasy-ish story, we have a diagram where four 'elements' and 3 'principles' (earth, fire, sulpher, etc) are (inter-)connected with each other. The interaction between each of these elements and principles are all described by a single words, such as for example: 'strengthens' and 'conquers' and 'absorbs'. All these interactions are single words (a fact that is also embedded into the backstory) one of these interactions could best be described as 'decays into', but since this is not a single word, it has to be either reworded by a synonym (the preferred option) or replaced by something else.

Hope this clarifies the question enough.

Comment: You'll be wanting 28 letters so that we can have more words next. 'Decay into' works fine.

Comment: Could you give an example sentence with a blank where you want your word, please? "Decay" is a technical term for radioactivity, and one element does *decay into* another (by the emission of alpha particles, say).

Comment: The 'into' rather implies you're about to tell us where the decay goes: "*Carbon-13 decays into nitrogen-12 and boron-12.*" If you want shorter, "decays to" is also used. If you don't want to tell us the decay product, just use "decays".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for the constructive comment.

Answer (score 3):

With the clarification, it seems you want a *transitive* verb,and the simplest one I can think of is **become**:

> Element A **becomes** element B.

It does, however, not cover the sense of decay, or breaking down. I doubt you will find a single verb that has a transitive meaning (explaining its relation to an *object*) while at the same time carrying an intransitive meaning (describing what the verb does to the *subject*)!

However, if you explain in context the process of A becoming B, I'm not sure you need the confirmation of "degeneration" in the used verb.

Comment: 'becomes' is rather neutral, the degeneration is part of what we are looking for. Some elements 'break down' other elements against their 'will'. (I'm aware this sounds rather non-scientific, but if you look at late 18th century texts, this is how things where actually thought of back then).

Comment: @Monika If between two elements, A decays into B, is that essentially different from "B absorbs A"? You mentioned _absorbs_ in your question. Is the word you are looking for not essentially the opposite, or passive, form of that? If A decays into B, it becomes B, so A is absorbed (or **assimilated**, more aggressively) by B. The problem is that you want a _transitive verb_, but you are concerned about the effect on the _subject_. That is a tough one, I can't think of an example where that works.

Comment: A -> B is different from B -> A, or at least, the word describes a different aspect of the interaction. As an example: *dissolves* is set opposite of *dilutes*. However, as you nicely pointed out, all interactions other than 'decays into' only say something about what A does to B. In the case of 'decays into' the interaction says something about both B and A. Maybe it is just not possible and the answer to the OP is 'No'?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, *degenerate* or *degrade* may be usable.

Comment: Wouldn't these similarly need the preposition OP so dislikes?

Comment: "'decays into' works fine'" ;-)